# How to bind a boolean value to checkboxcolumn datagrid WPF

Tags: wpf, binding, wpfdatagrid

i'm working on a project at a company for school and I have to make a datagrid with ticketinformation: The id-number, description of a ticket.

In my Tickettable in the database, I have a column 'Item' and it can have the values: "Not to be invoiced","To be invoiced" or "Offer". The 3rd column in the datagrid has to be a checkboxcolumn and my boss wants me that there is a possibility to check the checkbox, that means the ticket has to be invoiced, and when I uncheck, it means "not to be invoiced" or "offer", that doesn't really matter. My problem is when I bind the "ID" and "Description"-fields, I don't know how to bind the checkboxcolumn with a 'true or false' field? I only know how to bind tablefields from Ticket, but I want to add a boolean-field so I can determine in code when it's "to be invoiced", my boolean-field has to be true and when it's not to be invoiced, it has to be false, so unchecked.

```
dgTickets.DataContext = new List<ISSUE>(); 
dgTickets.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = "Id", Binding = new Binding("IM_ISSUE_NO") }); 
dgTickets.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = "Description", Binding = new Binding("IM_DESCRIPTION") }); 
DataGridCheckBoxColumn chk = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
chk.Header = "To be invoiced?";
List<ISSUE> lTickets = new List<ISSUE>(); 
lTickets = _ISSUEBO.getTickets(); 

//here I want to make a list of booleans when the tickets are 'to be invoiced or not' in the database
List<bool> lChecks = new List<bool>(); 
int intTeller = 0; 
bool boolFact = false;
foreach (ISSUE i in lTickets) {
switch (i.IM_ITEM_CODE) { 
case "TO BE INVOICED": 
boolFact = true; 
break; 
case "NOT TB INVOICED": 
boolFact = false; 
break; 
case "OFFER":
boolFact = false; 
break; 
default: break; 
} 
lChecks.Add(boolFact);
intTeller++; 
} 
Binding b = new Binding("lChecks"); //??? this is probably wrong, but i don't know how to do
chk.Binding = b;
this.dgTickets.Columns.Add(chk); 
dgTickets.ItemsSource = lTickets;
```

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand your need for the boolean list.

I'd use a converter and bind directly to the property. Something like this:

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
      public MainWindow()
      {
         InitializeComponent();

            DataGrid dgTickets = new DataGrid();

            ObservableCollection<ISSUE> Issues = new ObservableCollection<ISSUE>(); // better an ObservableCollection than a List here, so that it updates correctly when you modify the content.

            dgTickets.DataContext = Issues;

            dgTickets.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = "Id", Binding = new Binding("IM_ISSUE_NO") });
            dgTickets.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = "Description", Binding = new Binding("IM_DESCRIPTION") });
            dgTickets.Columns.Add(new DataGridCheckBoxColumn {
                Header = "To be invoiced?",
                Binding = new Binding("IM_ITEM_CODE") { Converter = new ItemCodeToBoolConverter() }
            });

      }
   }

    /// <summary>
    /// converts the item code string into a boolean
    /// </summary>
    public class ItemCodeToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string itemCode = (string)value;

            return (itemCode == "TO BE INVOICED");
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool toBeInvoiced = (bool)value;

            return toBeInvoiced ? "TO BE INVOICED" : "NOT TB INVOICED OR OFFER";
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1. And I'd reccomend to create ViewModel, expose Issues collection there, set ViewModel as MainWindow.DataContext, and declare DataGrid in XAML.

Comment: I did not go this far, since I'm guessing this will be a little overkill in this case ;) but you're right of course...

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the previous answer, I'd advise you to use more XAML. WPF's biggest advantage is that you can easily have independant view & model (thanks to the MVVM pattern)

In this case, you have a DataGrid which is displaying the content of a custom object, am I right?

First of all, are you familiar with data binding and OnPropertyChanged interface? If not you should definitely try to know more about that, which is really easy to use.

The way I'd do that is to add in your ViewModel a property "list", containing a list of the objects to be displayed.

Then, you can just declare your datagrid and bind it to the list:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding List}" >
```

And you can define templates for what is in the datagrid. In this case:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
   <!-- definition of the previous columns -->
   <DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
      <!-- Details on your checkbox here --> 
   </DataGridCheckBoxColumn> 
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

If you bind the checkBox to your boolean, it will be directly checked or not, according to the boolean value :-)

Comment: +1 xaml is life! :) though sometimes you can't go with xaml and have to stick to C#. This does not seem to be the case here anyway, so this would be worth a shot as well

Comment: It's my first 'bigger' WPF-project and I've heard about OnPropertyChanged, but I haven't used it yet. I'll give it a try. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does anyone know how I can access the eventhandler when I click on one of the checkboxes in the datagrid? I have to execute some code when there is clicked on one of the checkboxes.

Comment: What kind of code would you like to execute? You can use two-way binding from XAML. This means that when the property changes on the UI, it changes in your viewmodel as well, and works also in reverse way (changes in viewmodel are displayed by UI). You can just work in your property's set (which is called each time you change it on the UI): when it is set, it means the value actually changed. Oh, by the way, I'm speaking in a context in which you implement OnPropertyChanged :)

Comment: Yes, I can try it that way and indeed, it has to change in the database, but I also need to show a combobox for my teacher, with the value of the checkbox from the selected row, so that's why I want to know an eventhandler so that when I click on the checkbox, the combobox value change automatically

Comment: Well, it depends on how much time you have, but I'd really encourage you to take 2 days without coding on your project to discover the "WPF power" and especially the MVVM pattern (binding, viewmodels, "almost-no-code-behind" & OnPropertyChanged should be enough for you). I started to work in WPF only three weeks ago, it took me some days to understand the basic principles but now I can set up an architecture very easily, it's really worth knowing. And I guess it'll give you a better grade as well :-)

Comment: I'm working with NHibernate and i've read that there are a view issues with OnPropertychanged, do you have any experience with that?

Comment: I can't say anything about it since I have never worked with NHibernate, sorry, however I wonder what could be the problem since OnPropertyChanged has nothing to do with your database, therefore it should be totally independent of NHibernate, I guess...